# Best practice to Calling WebClient into Flux

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm trying to call a WebClient service into Flux method and value return type. I think to use doOnNext but I don't know how to do. Thanks in advance

```
public Flux<Product> streamData(List<Product> products) {
  return this.prodService.streamProducts(products).onBackpressureDrop()
  //.doOnNext (calling WebClient and setting product description)
    .doOnTerminate(() -> {
      log.info("Error data");
    })
    .doOnCancel(() -> {
      log.info("Close connection");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is your whole application reactive? I think you are mixing webflux with rxJava and reactor here.